# Case in where using Parameter

Tags: sql, case, where-clause

I would appreatiate an advice. I need to filter table valued function on parameter. If Parametr is '', it should return all items. If parameter is not '', it should apply filter.

```
create FUNCTION [dbo].[items] (@ItemGroupCode varchar(10)) 
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(

select * from items

left join ItemGroup on items.Iditemgroup = ItemGroup.Id

where 
case when ItemGroup.Code<>'' then ItemGroup.Code>=@ItemGroupCode end

)
```

This code does not work, query results on incorrect syntax on >=.
I would appreciate any advice.
Thank you!

Comment: It's generally better to use regular AND/OR instead of case expressions in the WHERE clause. I.e. try `where  @ItemGroupCode = '' or ItemGroup.Code >= @ItemGroupCode`.

Comment: The result of your case expression is a boolean. It seems your DBMS does not support the boolean data type.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the WHERE clause like this

```
WHERE ItemGroup.Code >=
CASE 
WHEN @ItemGroupCode<>'' THEN @ItemGroupCode 
ELSE
0 -- The minimum value of ItemGroup.Code
END
```

Supposing that the minimum value of ItemGroup.Code is >=0

Answer (score 0):

In your case, and generally, its much better to use `AND` `OR` operators to achieve your goal in `WHERE` clause.

You can modify your code like below:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[items] (@ItemGroupCode varchar(10)) 
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN (
    SELECT * 
    FROM [items]
    LEFT JOIN 
        [ItemGroup] 
    ON
        [items].[Iditemgroup] = [ItemGroup].[Id]
    WHERE
        [ItemGroup].[Code] = '' 
        OR [ItemGroup].[Code] >= @ItemGroupCode
)
```

Hope that'll answer your question.